ASP.NET Core ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS always overridden in VS Code debugger
I'm debugging an ASP.NET Core application in VS Code. My project has the following launchsettings.json:
{
  "profiles": {
    "Development": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS": "5003"
      }
    }
  }
}

which should set the port to 5003. Instead, when debugging, I get the message:

Overriding HTTP_PORTS '5003' and HTTPS_PORTS ''. Binding to values defined by URLS instead 'https://localhost:5001/'

Where is this value 5001 coming from?
If I use dotnet run my application uses the port 5003 as desired, it's only when debugging through VS Code that this other setting seems to override it, but I have no idea where this could be coming from.
Does VS Code inject env variables into the debugging session?


Does VS Code inject env variables into the debugging session?

Yes you are right, VS Code does inject environment variables into the debugging session, and this can override settings defined in launchSettings.json.
When you debug an ASP.NET Core application in VS Code, the debugger often uses launch.json settings, which can override the launchSettings.json file. VS Code may also automatically inject certain environment variables, including ASPNETCORE_URLS, which dictates the URL(s) your application should bind to. If ASPNETCORE_URLS is set, it will override the port settings from ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS.

Where is this value 5001 coming from?

Well, this port typically written in the file which resides in .vscode directory of your project. You can add the environment variable to ensure that the correct port is used during debugging.
Note: Please refer to this official document for additional details.

Could you share where your knowledge on this topic comes from? I can't find any VS Code documentation which says which variables are injected and with what values.

Well, sure you could take a look here and also this could be insightful

The way it looks, 1 link is to VS Code documentation and the other is to ASP.NET Core documentation. But nowhere is it mentioned that, and which, ASP.NET CORE environment variables are injected into VS Code Debugging sessions. Or did I miss something?

You're correct that neither the VS Code documentation nor the ASP.NET Core documentation explicitly mention which ASP.NET Core environment variables are injected into VS Code debugging sessions.
The behavior regarding environment variables like ASPNETCORE_URLS being set or overridden during a VS Code debugging session comes from a combination of general practices in how environment variables are handled in .NET Core and how the debugger in VS Code interacts with these settings.

Thank you for your help regardless, but  I guess I'll have to put this down to "it just seems to be that way" which is not really satisfying.

I would sugguest use Visual studio for purely working with asp.net core or anything .NET related backend development you would get better experience. VS code is light version most need extension for specific work and mostly prefereable for front-end development.
